# Switching order of matrices in matrix calculus equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

My professor (during deriving the closed form solution for Linear Regression) said

$\frac{\partial \theta^\intercal X^\intercal X\theta}{\partial \theta} = 2X^\intercal X \theta$

What are the rules for deciding to write
$\theta^\intercal X^\intercal X\theta$

and not
$\theta^2 X^\intercal X$

or to write
$2 X^\intercal X \theta$

and not
$2 \theta X^\intercal X$

If the reason is to make sure the dimensions match for matrix multiplication - then is it possible to reorder any terms in a multiplication to get a result in the dimensions you want or are there rules?

Comment: There are rules. You mentioned them yourself: make sure the dimensions match for matrix multiplication.

Comment: The definition of matrix multiplication tells you what you can or cannot do.